# Angular not loading external js files giving Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: jquery, css, angular, bootstrap-4, external-js

I'm trying to load a bootstrap template in angular. It got some external js and css files to which I need to link to. I'm putting them on assets and in angular.json I'm calling them in styles and scripts array like this:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/lib/animate/animate.min.css",
              "src/asstes/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css",
              "src/asstes/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css",
              "src/asstes/lib/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/asstes/lib/easing/easing.min.js",
              "src/asstes/lib/mobile-nav/mobile-nav.js",
              "src/asstes/lib/wow/wow.min.js",
              "src/asstes/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js",
              "src/asstes/lib/counterup/counterup.min.js",
              "src/asstes/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js",
              "src/asstes/lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
              "src/asstes/lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/main.js"
            ]
```

but when I'm trying to build the application I'm getting an error: **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'H:\digital\front\src\asstes\lib\easing\easing.min.js'**

I've updated npm, closed the terminal and opened it again, also used ng build but it keeps showing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see folder name "assets" is wrong. Change "asstes" by "assets".

Regards